# Passing this visual c++ redistributable 2017 x86 as prereq in my docker file is not installing

Tags: c++, docker

I have a docker image with prerequisite  visual c++ redistributable 2017 x86(exe) but after instantiating the container i see that this redistributable not installed.|
i went inside the container and try to install exe here manually  then also no luck

inside my docker file i used this run cmd 
RUN Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\tmp\prereq\vc_redist.x86.exe' -ArgumentList '/quiet /install /norestart' -Wait; \
  Remove-Item 'c:\tmp\prereq\vc_redist.x86.exe'

```
My docker file below
```

FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]
MAINTAINER

## Install Windows features for IIS

RUN Add-WindowsFeature Web-server, NET-Framework-45-ASPNET, Web-Asp-Net45
RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationDevelopment,IIS-ASPNET45,IIS-WindowsAuthentication

RUN New-Item -Path 'c:/tmp/prereq' -ItemType Directory
COPY ./prereq "c:\tmp\prereq"

RUN Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\tmp\prereq\vc_redist.x64.exe' -ArgumentList '/q' -Wait; \
  Remove-Item 'c:\tmp\prereq\vc_redist.x64.exe'

COPY ./website "c:\iis\website"

RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'; \
  New-Website -Name 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath 'C:\inetpub' -Port 80; \
  New-WebApplication -Name "QualityWebService" -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath 'c:\iis\website' -ApplicationPool "DefaultAppPool"; \
  Invoke-Command -scriptblock {iisreset}

EXPOSE 80

Comment: do you have any logs you can share? Dockerfile as well?

Comment: i don't have any logs but in my container on this path i cant find the registry entry for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_amd64,v14  -> not present

Comment: FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]
 
# Install Windows features for IIS
RUN Add-WindowsFeature Web-server, NET-Framework-45-ASPNET, Web-Asp-Net45
RUN Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationDevelopment,IIS-ASPNET45,IIS-WindowsAuthentication

Comment: RUN New-Item -Path 'c:/tmp/prereq' -ItemType Directory
COPY ./prereq "c:\tmp\prereq"
RUN Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\tmp\prereq\vc_redist.x86.exe' -ArgumentList '/quiet /install /norestart' -Wait; 
  Remove-Item 'c:\tmp\prereq\vc_redist.x86.exe'
COPY ./website "c:\iis\website"
RUN Remove-WebSite -Name 'Default Web Site'; \
  New-Website -Name 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath 'C:\inetpub' -Port 80; \
  New-WebApplication -Name "WebService" -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath 'c:\iis\website' -ApplicationPool "DefaultAppPool"; \
  Invoke-Command -scriptblock {iisreset}    
EXPOSE 80

Comment: Doing a windows update sometimes resolves this problem

Comment: edit your original post and put Dockerfile and logs there, comments, are not place for it. Why you do not have any logs? There's no console output while you build the image?

Comment: yes i have added  docker file in the above post   also   i will add my container logs

Comment: i font one thing MSACM32.dll is not present inside my container (path C:\Windows\System32) i manually try to add but still no luck